# Log4Net Not Writing to Output File

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net

I'm having serious trouble getting log4net to work with a Windows service (multi-project solution).

I first added reference to log4net.dll to the appropriate projects via NuGet. I then created a new `Log4Net.config` file in the root folder of the Windows service project. In the file's properties, I set `Copy to Output Directory = Copy always`. Below is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="TestServiceLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="C:\Temp\Test.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <priority value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="TestServiceLog" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

In my Windows service project, in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, I added this line:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

In my main `TestService.cs` class, I referenced log4net and initialized the logger like so (omitted non-logging code):

```
public partial class TestService : ServiceBase
{
    private ILog Log { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Log = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
        Log.Info("Hear me log.");
    }
}
```

I then installed and ran the service. I validated the service is running normally, but no log file is created/written to. No exceptions are being thrown. Everything appears in order when debugging. I turned on log4net's internal debugging and got this:

```
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [TestService, Version=3.6.5570.17497, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [TestService, Version=3.6.5570.17497, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [C:\ProgramData\Company\Applications\TestService\TestService\TestService.exe]
log4net: Assembly [TestService, Version=3.6.5570.17497, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [TestService, Version=3.6.5570.17497, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: repository [log4net-default-repository] already exists, using repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
```

The output does not seem to hint at any issues. I've also tried adding the following line to my configuration, but it didn't do the trick:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
```

I added a WinForms project to the solution with the exact same configuration and logging worked fine, so I'm confident it's not my setup. Any other ideas on steps I may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by making the `Log` variable static and instantiating it like this:

```
private static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TestService));
```

I'm not quite sure why this was necessary. Hopefully someone else knows the answer.